# PyQt chat emoticon popup window

Tags: python, pyqt, chat

How can I create a popup emoticon widget for a chat client? I found this source :
http://bit.ly/wMZyTQ , but the function `reinit()` is a bit complicated.

Can anyone help me understand it? Does anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be clear and usable to me. I do understand that there is a lot of stuff going on in that bit of code. Why don't you try taking it one step at a time? That's my recommendation.

There might be a somewhat simpler way to do this, depending on your specific circumstances. For instance, you could try laying out QLabels in a grid layout and specify the emoticons by putting them in the labels. You'd have to do a bit of work to have the program react correctly on click and such, but it would work. This idea may not be great, since I haven't tested it in practice. I haven't used Qt in a while, so I might have missed something. In any case, this may or may not be a good fit for you. The labels might grow too big for instance. The code you linked to has greater control over the process, as far as I can tell.

I hope this helps.